# How to get the first ul inside div having a class name

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to get the first `ul` inside `div` having a class name **makers** . I tried this but it's throwing an error `'list' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

This is what I tried:

```
div = base_category_soup.select("div.makers")
print div.find_all("ul")
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is `div`?  What do the docs say `.select(...` returns?  Do you understand  what the error means?  Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find find_all can't use with select's result

You can check the type of your result to know it

And,in this case,I will use find or find_all to find the target

Try it

`target = base_category_soup.find('div',class_='markers').find('ul')`

It must be "first ul in first div its class is markers"

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the error tells you all you need to know. As div is a list you need to dereference it, e.g:

```
div[0].find_all("ul")
```

If the first div element is the one you want or if there is only one of them.

Comment: This will fail if the first `div.makers` does not contain any `ul`s.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`nth-of-type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo) CSS pseudo-class (supported by BeautifulSoup):

```
ul = base_category_soup.select('div.makers ul:nth-of-type(1)')
```

or, a simple Python item getter:

```
ul = base_category_soup.select('div.makers ul')[0]
```

Note that both of these will get you **the first `ul` from the first `div.makers` that actually contains an `ul` element**, whereas `div[0].find_all('ul')` will fail in the case the first `div` does not contain any `ul`s.